# Scroll to the bottom solutions not always going to the absolute end of the page

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, puppeteer

**scenario**

I am scraping the comments from a YouTube video's page using Puppeteer. The ajax call to fetch more comments is called when we scroll to the absolute bottom of the page, thus I need to scroll to the bottom.

**problem**

The problem is I am not able to; even if I apply a scrolling to bottom solution it sometimes does not scroll to the end of the page, means it goes to the bottom, but not absolute bottom, leaving some gap below, because of which the ajax call is not triggered

**solutions I have tried**

1. the page.scroll() function of puppteer [failed].
2. `document.querySelector('body').scrollIntoView({block: "end"})` [not working on youtube pages, working only on some websites]
3. `document.scrollingElement.scrollTop =(document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight)` [at times does not go to the absolute bottom]
4. `document.scrollingElement.scrollTop =(document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight) + 999999` [same as above]
5. `window.scrollBy() & window.scrollTo()`

There could be one or more JS solutions I have tried and failed to solve the problem.

PS since I am working on puppeteer, browser compatibility on other browsers like firefox or IE not required I suppose

Comment: What happens if you insert an element before the end of the body and scroll to that?

Comment: Haven't tried such a solution yet ^

Comment: Already mentioned that in my question

Comment: I did, I said to the absolute end of the page. To the bottom; so that the ajax call can be triggered. And in the question I just mentioned that I used this function, but in my program I wrote it correctly

Comment: Is it possible to create [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi @Aankhen my problem's solved (using a different method) and I have posted the answer. But if you're still interested in finding out why the above methods were not working I can post a mock script. It's a puppeteer code, not really sure how would I create an MCVE for it.

Comment: That’s okay, I’m glad it was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did

When you first load a youtube video's page and scroll down, first thing you encounter (and the last element at the moment) is comment box with selector `ytd-comments#comments`, and then when the comments starts loading, the last comment's element with selector `ytd-comment-thread-renderer.style-scope.ytd-item-section-renderer` is the last element on the page (at that moment).

So instead of scrolling down the page (and taking a cue from @mplungjan 's comment ) I scrolled down to these elements with this code

```
var flag_a =0, flag_b=0;

const COMMENTS_SCROLL_SELECTORS ={
    COMMENT_BOX: 'ytd-comments#comments',
    COMMENT_LAST: 'ytd-comment-thread-renderer.style-scope.ytd-item-section-renderer'
}

page.on('response', response => {
    if (<the url which brings comment>){
        ++flag_b;
    }
});

setInterval(() => {
    scrollToBottom();
}, 5000);


async function scrollToBottom(){
    if(flag_a == flag_b){
        await page.evaluate((COMMENTS_SCROLL_SELECTORS) => {
            var ele = document.querySelector(COMMENTS_SCROLL_SELECTORS.COMMENT_LAST);

            if(ele){
                //first scroll already performed, so perform subsequent scrolls
                var length = document.querySelectorAll(COMMENTS_SCROLL_SELECTORS.COMMENT_LAST).length;
                ele = document.querySelectorAll(COMMENTS_SCROLL_SELECTORS.COMMENT_LAST)[length - 1];
                ele.scrollIntoView();
            }else{
                //perform first scroll
                ele = document.querySelector(COMMENTS_SCROLL_SELECTORS.COMMENT_BOX);
                ele.scrollIntoView();
            }

        }, COMMENTS_SCROLL_SELECTORS);

        ++flag_a;
    }else{
        process.exit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try follow like:**

```
let previousHeight;
while (true) {
  try {
    previousHeight = await page.evaluate('document.body.scrollHeight')
    await page.evaluate('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)')
    await page.waitForFunction(`document.body.scrollHeight > ${previousHeight}`)
    // .....
    // Something
    // .....
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Scroll End Page')
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: not working at all. Just enters the try block and that's it